# How do I resolve a circular dependency in ES6 modules with a factory function?

Tags: module, ecmascript-6, factory

I want to write something like this inside my `src/core/Chessman.js` file:

```
import King from './chessmen/King'

class Chessman {
  static factory(side, quality) {
    switch(quality) {
      case 'king' : return new King(side) break
      // ... other qualities
    }

    constructor(side) { this.side = side }

    cast(position, ref) { }

    run(position, startRef, endRef) {}
  }
```

and inside my `src/core/chessmen/King.js` file:

```
import Chessman from '../Chessman'

class King extends Chessman {

  constructor(side) {
    super(side)
    this.iterative = false // true for Queens, Rooks and Bishop
    this.directions = [
      'up', 'up+right', 'right', 'right+down', 
      'down', 'down+left', 'left', 'left+top'
    ]
  }

  // overrides parent behavior
  cast(position, ref) {}
  run(position, startRef, endRef) {}
}
```

But sadly I get the error (while testing) with Karma, jasmine and babel

> TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
>     at src/core/chessmen/King.js:57

And there's no line 57 for the moment in `King.js` !

Comment: finally I opted to sperate clearly concerns : basically, for the king, three files : ./core/Chessman.js, ./chessmen/King.js and ./factories/Chessmen.js ... all works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular dependency error. Given what you've shown us, consider the following steps:

1. `Chessman.js` starts loading
2. It pauses execution so its dependencies can load.
3. `King.js` starts loading since it is a dependency.
4. `King.js` throws because `class King extends Chessman` runs, but `Chessman` has not been set yet, because it paused on step #2

You'd be much better off moving your factory function to its own file, to avoid cyclical dependencies. The only safe circular dependencies in JS are ones that are not needed when the module itself is initialized. Since `class extends X` runs at module initialization time, it is not safe for cycles.

If this was literally your only class, you could write your app such that `King.js` was imported before `Chessman.js`, but given your usage of a factory, and your naming scheme, I assume there are other chess pieces. Since every single chess piece class will trigger this issue, there is no way to import them in the correct order. Avoiding the issue by moving the factory function out of `Chessman.js` is the only solution to this.

Comment: Nice ! yes there are other chessmen... so I will move the factory to its own module. Thanks for all !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a factory, instead of saving it directly in the base class module, move it to it's own module - `chessman.factory.js`. There, do whatever `Chessman.factory` does in a method or something. This way the `chessman.js` module wouldn't have to know about modules that need itself,